# How to fix wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress, web, browser, plugins

I have created my website on a Brave browser. it works perfectly, but when I use others browsers like chrome, firefox, all other browsers, some pages are missing, some texts are not there.

**What could be the cause and solution for this?**

Thanx

Comment: Open up your browsers' dev tools. F12 on Windows machines. Look at the console log. Does it have any error messages? Ask another question that's more specific.

Comment: Yes, very hard to answer your question with so little information to go on. If it's a Wordpress site, have you tried editing the site on Chrome or FF. Does that work?